# Delphi TButton image position

Tags: image, delphi, button, alignment, delphi-xe8

In Delphi XE8, the `TButton` image has aligning for "left, center, right and bottom" but when I select "center" align for the image, the image aligns in the middle of the button and stays behind the caption

What I wanna do is align the image right before the caption text (like it should)

I don't know why Delphi `TButton` doesn't do that, is it a bug? Or Delphi team want to drive us crazy? It should be so easy but just aligning a button image causing problems?

Is there a way to align the image nicely in the center with the caption?

like in the picture below

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the TButton.ImageAlignment property?

Comment: You could manually paint the icon in the button and then paint the text.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it is bitbtn it was very simple and it is there always in front of my eyes, apperantly bitbtn is also a wrapper for OS button, it does what i ask for and also it has canvas so drawing on it is possible

Answer (score 0):

The text in the button is one thing the image is another. You could hack this if you align the image to the left, and align the text in the middle. If needed add extra blank spaces in front of the text.

Comment: If i align the image to the left and add extra space before text it is like right opposite of what i wanna do

Comment: Add the space at the end of the text.

Comment: But i dont think it is right way to do adding spaces before/after text, there must be a right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the TButton with a TBitBtn, and use the margin property of TBitBtn to align images nicely.

The Margin property sets the distance between the edge of the button and glyph, in pixels.

More info here:
https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/TBitBtn